# Checking if class is child of class

Tags: java, classloader

I am loading classes via ClassLoader:

```
Class<?> clazz = urlClassLoader.loadClass(name.substring(0, name.length() - 6).replaceAll("/", "."));
System.out.println(clazz);
System.out.println(clazz.isInstance(SkillCast.class));
System.out.println(SkillCast.class.isInstance(clazz));
System.out.println(SkillCast.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz));
System.out.println(clazz.isAssignableFrom(SkillCast.class));
```

This is my structure:

```
public class SkillFireball extends SkillCast implements ISkillThrown
public abstract class SkillCast extends Skill
```

And prints are:

```
class skills.SkillFireball
false
false
false
false
```

What I am sure of is that clazz is SkillFireball and I can print field/method names.

**How can I check if clazz is child of SkillCast?**

EDIT

```
private static URLClassLoader urlClassLoader;
```

And code:

```
ClassLoader cl = Loader.instance().getModClassLoader();
urlClassLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls.toArray(new URL[urls.size()]), cl);
```

Where #getModClassLoader() returns:

```
    // The class loader we load the mods into.
    private ModClassLoader modClassLoader;
```

And:

```
public class ModClassLoader extends URLClassLoader
```

How it works:
Minecraft Forge API is loading @Mod. My mod is providing SkillCast.class and when loaded is attempting to read game directory and load classes in .jar files. Now - I have not much of an idea what should I do :C

Comment: `SkillCast.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)` *does* tel you whether `clazz` is a subclass of `SkillCast`. Are you sure you don't have more than one class called SkillCast (including when the same class file loaded by different classloaders)?

Comment: I am sure that there is only one SkillCast. What might be important is the fact that SkillCast is loaded by different ClassLoader (main program) and actual skill.jar-s are loaded using different classLoader - can this be the problem?

Comment: If the same class file is loaded by two different classloaders, that creates two different classes.

Comment: What is the parent of your `urlClassLoader`?

Comment: Check whether `urlClassLoader.loadClass("skills.SkillCast") != SkillCast.class` to know whether you have two different SkillCast classes by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I did it.

Problem was really my lack of knowledge about how classLoader-parenting works and how Java loads classes.

Done it by making new URLClassLoader with parent set to ClassLoader used by Main program itself (the mentioned @Mod).

SkillCast.class is loaded by Mod's ClassLoader therefore when I added new Class (SkillFireball) I also needed to use Mod's one, not new one like I did before.

```
Class<?> clazz = Loader.instance().getModClassLoader().loadClass(...)
```

This is not really an "answer" just an closing-problem post.